# display monthly attendance report of an employee

Tags: sql

I have a table called empattendancetable in which the fields are eid,empname,designation,logindatetime, status

logindatetime's  value is  from datetimepicker but i want to display the attendance report monthwise of each employee

I am not getting the query to display the details of employees attendance monthwise so anybody let me know how to write the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with this and see what happens:

```
SELECT eid 'ID',empname 'Name', month(logindatetime) 'Month', count(*) 'Attendance'
FROM empattendancetable 
WHERE month(logindatetime)=@month
GROUP BY eid,empname, month(logindatetime)
```

Comment: ID Name  month  Attendance
Emp001 abcd  5  3
Emp001 abcd  6  1

Comment: suppose in a combobox if i have all the month names starting from jan to dec
then how to get details of selected value.. i dont want to mention the month name in the query because the user will randomly from the combobox.. i want to display monthly attendance report of that particular month.. how to do it sir

Comment: @sangeethakumar please edit yous question and add data sample and expected results.

Comment: sir i just want to display how many days an employee was present on that particular month, if i select the id from combobox and monthnname from combobox i want to display eid,empname,month,noofdays

Comment: sir i am getting the proper output using what the query you had given but my requirement is to get based on the month names selected from the combobox

Comment: @sangeethakumar I just edited the answer, now could you formaly accept it? You need to pass number month via parameters from code. If you don't know how to do it, ask a new question.

Comment: SELECT eid 'ID',empname 'Name', month(logindatetime) 'Month', count(*) 'Attendance' FROM empattendancetable  GROUP BY eid,empname, month(logindatetime) WHERE month(logindatetime)=@month

Comment: incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE this is the error i am getting

Comment: @sangeethakumar look at answer again. You need to declare `@month` as parameter or replace it whit your month number from application code

Comment: SELECT eid 'ID',empname 'Name', month(logindatetime) 'Month', count(*) 'Attendance' FROM empattendancetable  WHERE month(logindatetime)='" + comboBox2.Text + "' GROUP BY eid,empname, month(logindatetime)    this query is not working sir, no error but no output also sir